# Are there any pooling solutions that allow a key to be passed to the acquire/take method

Tags: java, pool

I have a need to pool connections to some resource. The actual resource is not important for this discussion. The thing of note however is that these connections are not threadsafe, thus the need for pooling as connecting etc is an expensive operation.

My original idea was for one big pool which manages the timing out of connections and kills them etc. However the problem is each connection may include a different parameter, thus when taking the connection it is necessary to pass the parameter and let the pooler use this to attempt to find a connection with the same value. If it (the pool) could not find the object it then needs to create an instance passing the parameter of course etc.

However Apache Commons Pools and ohter similar libraries do not have any provision for this sort of concept. Are there any libraries which include this sort of concept. I suppose underneath the Pool holds a list of instances and when a take request comes in it uses some matcher to loop over its available objects and returns the first that is matched.

Note it is not possible to chnage the parameter of the connection object thus the problem and the reason for the question being asked.

- Is there a better way to solve this problem  ?
- Is there a pooling library that does the above ?
- Should i just write my own ?

Comment: why can't you just configure diff pools for diff parameters. have a facade for access to all these pools. if facade knows there is no pool for the given input parameter then it would create one on the fly

Comment: Because there are too many different parameters, which would mean lots and lots of pools. As i have mentioned in other comment - i believe that apache commons pools arent cheap as each pool creates its own cleanup thread. From my quick look there does not appear to be an easy way to get ACP to share the cleanup thread so each pool creation is more or less a cheap queue w/ a background cleanup thread and the lifecycle management thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you check [KeyedObjectPool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool/KeyedObjectPool.html) in apache Pool?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the key to find the pool first? Then use one of the available solutions. I don't think you would be simplifying anything by trying to pool everything together since differently-keyed items are not cross-compatible.

Comment: Because following your advice most of these 2nd level pools will have most of the time one item. Each key will probably have only one instance, and there is a small chance for the current thread wanting this connection back again. However there is a small chance other threads might need the connection hence the practical want to pool. I am not sure exactly but it appears that creating apache commons pools is not cheap as each one i think creates its own cleanup the pool thread.

Comment: I'd recommend evaluating whether you actually have overhead problems you are worried about before going about trying to devise a solution that avoids them. Maybe your work load is such that you will not notice a difference in performance... Simple first, then measure and optimize as actually necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If the object is not thread-safe, why pooling?  Your pool manager won't be able to check the status / close them from other thread anyway.

Just keep one copy in each thread using `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: I think you have missed the whole point of pooling. While the object is given out no one else can use it. I cant keep a ThreadLocal because there will be many connections which are probably never reused by this thread but overall there is a reasonable chance they will be reused.

Comment: So? You except the pooling manger do the clean up for you? No, it won't work that way. Pool do cleanup either on next allocation (which never happen in your case), or in separate thread. Since your connection are not thread-safe, you can't clean up on other thread.

Comment: I think you are wrong w/ your understanding of what a pool cleanup means. When some pooled item has not been used for some period of time you set, the pool will call a destroy this item on some helper. THe entire point of pools is to hand out an instance to only one user at a time.

Answer (score 0):

KeyedObjectPool is the answer and if you want to see an example have a look at [this](http://rdafbn.blogspot.ie/2013/02/pool-of-ssh-connections-using-apache.html)